# Error importing mobiscroll css styles in webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, loader, mobiscroll

I have a problem with importing mobiscroll css styles in my react project (created by webpack)
Other css files are working well but
This line generates Error:

```
import '@mobiscroll/react-lite/dist/css/mobiscroll.min.css'
```

The generated Error:

```
./node_modules/@mobiscroll/react-lite/dist/css/icons_mobiscroll.ttf?vtxdtu 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file) 

./node_modules/@mobiscroll/react-lite/dist/css/icons_mobiscroll.woff?vtxdtu 1:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

./node_modules/@mobiscroll/react-lite/dist/css/icons_mobiscroll.woff 1:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

and my webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const CSSModuleLoader = {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
        modules: {
            localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
        },
        sourceMap: true
    }
};

const CSSLoader = { loader: 'css-loader' };

const PostCSSLoader = {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
        ident: 'postcss',
        sourceMap: false, // turned off as causes delay
        plugins: () => [
            autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['>1%', 'last 4 versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'not ie < 9']
            })
        ]
    }
};

const StyleLoader = {
    loader: 'style-loader'
};

const SassLoader = {
    loader: 'sass-loader'
};

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{loader: 'html-loader'}]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                exclude: /\.module\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [StyleLoader, CSSLoader, PostCSSLoader, SassLoader]
            },
            {
                test: /\.module\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [StyleLoader, CSSModuleLoader, PostCSSLoader, SassLoader]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|png|jpe?g|gif|bmp)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=img/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [ // for copying the content of 'public/static' folder to 'dist' folder
                { from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/static'), to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/static')}
            ]
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: __dirname + '/public/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        }),

    ]
};
```

my webpack configuration is working well for all other css or scss files but can not load that css file. what's the problem?
please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my mistake. I haven't defined a loader for font files and that css file was using some fonts.
This solved my Problem:

```
{
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
    // exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        limit: 1024,
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        publicPath: 'dist/assets/',
        outputPath: 'dist/assets/'
    }
}
```